# Unresolved reference: sun.misc.MessageUtils.where

Tags: android, import, kotlin, libraries

I suddenly got this problem..

I have searched, but no results.

any suggestions?

Thank u guys. 
[image]

Comment: `sun.*` are internal packages. Don't use them. And AFAIK, they are not included in the Android SDK

Comment: So, can I just remove the line? @Zoe

Comment: If you don't use it, yes. If you for whatever reason use MessageUtils.where, don't use it.

Comment: ökay man.. thank u a löt. I remöved it.. it wörks.. thank U :D